# Using TextureView with MediaPlayer on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: android, textureview

I've been struggling with this for ages, and I cannot figure out the problem.

I want to develop an application that plays a video, using TextureView and a MediaPlayer. It all runs great, on all devices tested except for Samsung Galaxy S2, android 4.0.4. It doesn't seem to call onSurfaceTextureAvailable.

Thank you

Comment: No one know about this? I read that this could be a Samsung S2 driver problem. Is is true?